# GAE python threads not executing in parallel

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to create a simple web app using Python on GAE. The app needs to spawn some threads per request received. For this I am using python's threading library. I spawn all the threads and then wait on them.

```
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

The application runs fine except for the fact that the threads are running serially rather than concurrently(confirmed this by printing the timestamps at the beginning/end of each thread's run() method). I have followed the instructions given in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27.html#Multithreading to enable multithreading

My app.yaml looks like:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /stylesheet
  static_dir: stylesheet

- url: /javascript
  static_dir: javascript

- url: /pages
  static_dir: pages

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

I made sure that my local GoogleAppLauncher uses python 2.7 by setting the path explicitly in the preferences.

My threads have an average run-time of 2-3 seconds in which they make a url open call and do some processing on the result.

Am I doing something wrong, or missing some configuration to enable multithreading?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you experiencing this in the dev_appserver or after uploading your app to the production service?  From your mention of GoogleAppLauncher it sounds like you may be seeing this in the dev_appserver; the dev_appserver does not emulate the threading behavior of the production servers, and you'd be surprised to find that it works just fine after you deploy your app.  (If not, add a comment here.)

Another idea: if you are mostly waiting for the urlfetch, you can run many urlfetch calls in parallel by using the async interface to urlfetch:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html

This approach does not require threads.  (It still doesn't properly parallelize the requests in the dev_appserver; but it does do things properly on the production servers.)

Comment: Yeah I was experiencing the problem on my local installation only. The threads ran in parallel when I uploaded my app. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The multithreading notes for GAE are merely for how requests are handled - they don't fundamentally change how Python threads work.  Specifically, the "CPython Implementation Detail" note in the [threading module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) still applies.

It's also worth mentioning the note in the "Sandboxing" section of the GAE docs:

> Note that threads will be joined by the runtime when the request ends,
>   so the threads cannot run past the end of the request.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the response. So, does the multithreading support in GAE imply that the GAE can spawn multiple threads to handle requests in parallel, but the application code itself cannot spawn helper threads?

Comment: @Nitesh: The front-end that hands requests to you is capable of spawning multiple instances of your application to handle those requests, however the threads you create in each instance are still bound by normal rules.  You can of course spawn helper threads, but they will not run concurrently unless they are blocking on I/O.

Comment: In the helper threads, I am making a urllib.urlopen call. Isn't this call I/O blocked?

Comment: So in GAE, urllib is not implemented in the same manner as in your local python: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html  Whether these calls behave similarly in threads is not covered in the documentation.

Comment: Nick, bringing up the "CPython Implementation Detail" (i.e. the GIL) here is irrelevant since the threads here are I/O-bound so they are not limited by the GIL -- it is released as soon as a thread blocks for I/O (such as a urlfetch call or a datastore operation).  So Nitesh is right, and concurrent threads making calls ro urlfetch or urlopen *do* run concurrently, even if the docs don't explicitly cover it.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum: Good to know - barring documentary evidence to the contrary, it seemed sensible to assume that one could not expect concurrency in the `urlfetch` API.

Answer (score 0):

If your threads are mostly waiting for datastore operations, you may try the [NDB](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/) module that's part of 1.6.2. The semantics will be close enough to what you are doing.

IIRC, the multithreading flag enables one server instance to serve multiple requests on separate threads, but won't allow you to start threads yourself. If you didn't need to sync them before returning, you could put them on separate [tasks](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) and delegate them to one or more task queues.

Comment: Actually, the Py27 runtime does allow creating threads.  (But see the note added in the first answer above -- they will be joined when the request ends.)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, and for the advice much better than mine.

Comment: There is a new feature called "background threads", which are like regular threads, except that background threads are not implicitly joined at the end of a request: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/background_thread