# Is there a way to speed up task queue execution of the with the python dev server?

Tags: google-app-engine

It appears the simulated task queue that ships with the development server processes tasks serially. Is there a way to run tasks concurrently with the **dev server**? I'm assuming with the 2.7 threadsafe stuff, this should be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no! Forget about the dev server for the more advanced work is my advice, deploy deploy deploy!

GVR says:

> the dev_appserver does not emulate the threading behavior of the production servers, and you'd be surprised to find that it works just fine after you deploy your app.

from a similar question: [GAE python threads not executing in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351719/gae-python-threads-not-executing-in-parallel)

Although that's relevant to tasks, you have to assume that if the threading behaviour of the servers is not emulated on the dev server neither is the 'threaded' task behaviour.