# Does GAE support writing multithreaded code for python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Does GAE support using modules like multiprocessing?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you search before asking? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351719/gae-python-threads-not-executing-in-parallel  or   http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- I guess I was looking for some more specifics on how to implement multithreaded code. I have "threadsafe: true" on my app.yaml file, but do I use "multiprocessing" or some other module for starting threads?

Comment: THere are a bunch of reasons why threads are not particularly useful on appengine.  You have said why you need them. Backend modules make use of threads, but front end requests you will find are not suitable. You have a lot of async methods which suit front ends requests better.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, "threadsafe: true" is used to make sure than a single instance can process multiple requests in parallel safely.

Before you try to use multiple threads to process a single request, examine your use case. In most situations you can use asynchronous calls to avoid waiting time. If you do, there are very little benefits (or none at all) from using multiple threads.

If you want to make massive parallel calculations, use [MapReduce](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/).